# How to fix the array created in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage

this array I created returns null but I can access its length with the "length" method. If the array is recognized and I can see its length, I can't find my error why I get a "null" value. The codes are below, thanks in advance for your answers.

```
const todos = ["Todo 1","Todo 2","Todo 3"];
console.log(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
```

Comment: You still would have to put the data in the localstorage to be able to retrieve it later. `const` doesn't do that for you.

Comment: localStorage stores only string. try `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 const todos = ["Todo 1","Todo 2","Todo 3"]; 
 
 localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(todos))
 console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it returns null because you haven't put `todos` in the localstorage. to do that you do `localStorage.setItem("todos", todos)` where the string `todos` is the name for the localstorage. it can be `foo`, `strawberry` or `banana` or anything, as long it's a string.

Localstorage only supports text, so you do `localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(todos))`. and to get your result just do `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"))` and you're set!

```
const todos = ["Todo 1","Todo 2","Todo 3"];
localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(todos))
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")));
```